Pyspark transformation causing out of memory issues
So I have a spark dataframe with multiple columns which are complex structs. I am trying to transform the value of a field in one of the struct columns based on the value of a field in another struct column. I am working with spark 3.5 so I am using the withField function. The transformation:
df = df.withColumn(
    "Column_1", 
    F.when(
    F.col("Column_2.field_2").isNotNull(), F.col("Column_1").withField("field_1", F.col("Column_2.field_2")*F.lit(1000000))
    ))

I am trying to update the value of Column_1.field_1 based on the value of Column_2.field_2.
When I try to display/write the dataframe after the transformation, it takes a long time and the cluster driver crashes with the following error:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : GC overhead limit exceeded
Is this not the correct way to use withField? It does not give me any error while planning or providing the output of df.explain(). Although it does take significantly more time to give out the output of df.explain() (50-60s compared to a second or two for other chain of transformations).
Also the amount of data in the dataframe is pretty low(with a lot of nulls in thr complex structs), less than 100 rows and few hundred KBs in delta.

The transformation looks okay. Is this the only transformation involved? What is your cluster configuration?

Yes I was able to isolate this particular transformation as the cause. It is actually after a bunch of transformations but I saved the dataframe as a delta table and read it to start the lineage just before applying this. The cluster I'm using is having 4 cores-32gb(e4 highmem.in gcp) as drivers and workers.

Not sure why ~ 100 rows with a few KBs of data would cause a GC error. Are there other jobs running on your interactive cluster? I'd restart the cluster before even looking any further.

Nothing at all. I'm running this on databricks on an isolated cluster which does not have any tasks or jobs running. my thinking was that the large number of complex struct columns would be causing the query plan to go large but there are only two fields I'm using

Others can chime but honestly, given the details, it would be difficult to comment without looking at the exact code and some sample data which is causing the error.

As far as the code is concerned this is essentially it. I can't really share the data but let me see if I can recreate this bug using dummy data of similar structure.

What if you turn spark.sql.adaptive.enabled off?

So it seems issue was with the complexity of the schema. I had within the same dataframe multiple struct columns with 100s of fields and all of that was becoming part of the plan even though most of the columns were null.

out of memory error while trying to transform a Spark DataFrame with complex struct columns.
The error message you are seeing indicates that the garbage collector is spending too much time trying to free up memory,
which can happen when there is not enough memory available to the JVM.
One reason for this error is that the amount of memory allocated to the Spark driver is not sufficient to handle the size of the DataFrame.
You can try increasing the amount of memory allocated to the driver by setting the spark.driver.memory configuration property.
For example, you can set it to 8g to allocate 8 GB of memory to the driver:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("ccapp") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "8g") \
    .getOrCreate()

As you mentioned you are trying to update the value of Column_1.field_1 based on the value of Column_2.field_2.
I have tried the below approach as an example:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
struct_schema_1 = StructType([
    StructField("_1", IntegerType()),
    StructField("_2", StringType())
])
struct_schema_2 = StructType([
    StructField("_1", IntegerType()),
    StructField("_2", StringType())
])
data = [
    ((10, "value_1"), (20, "value_2")),
    ((30, "value_3"), (None, "value_4")),
    ((50, "value_5"), (60, "value_6")),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, StructType([
    StructField("Column_1", struct_schema_1),
    StructField("Column_2", struct_schema_2)
]))
df = df.withColumn(
    "Column_1", 
    F.when(
        F.col("Column_2._1").isNotNull(),
        F.struct(
            F.col("Column_1._1") * F.col("Column_2._1"),
            F.col("Column_1._2")
        ).cast(struct_schema_1)
    ).otherwise(F.col("Column_1"))
)
df.show(truncate=False)

Results:
+---------------+---------------+
|Column_1       |Column_2       |
+---------------+---------------+
|{200, value_1} |{20, value_2}  |
|{30, value_3}  |{NULL, value_4}|
|{3000, value_5}|{60, value_6}  |
+---------------+---------------+

